# Changing Dynamic port in tomcat configuration

Tags: tomcat, server.xml

I am doing the below change in server.xml in tomcat 7.0

```
<Connector port="${httpPort}" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

I need to append 1 before the httpPort like 1${httpPort} so that for 8080 the https port will be 18080, I have tried the below things, it doesn't work, Please help. Thanks!

port="1${httpPort}"
port=1"${httpPort}"
port="1+${httpPort}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that its not possible to dynamically alter the port in server.xml, introduced a new server start up argument and passed that in https port.